# Custom Django signal receiver getting data

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm very new to programming and especially to Django but can't work out how to use any previous answers to my advantage....

Apologies if my question is too vague but essentially, I have two different apps, let's call them app A and app B, with data on two different databases but apps contain information on the same individual item.

I want to edit this information on my 'edit details' page while keeping the apps as separate as possible (well AppB can know about functions in AppA but not vice-versa)...I guess what I really want is a signal which works like so:

1. A 'submit' view within AppA which is called when I submit changes to the data (using text boxes). The data for AppA is then saved..
2. And a signal then sent to AppB which ideally would update its data, before the HttpResponseRedirect is performed.

Unfortunately I can't really get this to work. My problem is that if I put 'request' into the arguments for save_details, I get errors like "save_details() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)"....does anyone know a clever way of getting something like this to work?

My submit function in AppA looks something like this...

```
    def submit(self, request, id):
        signal_received.send(sender=self, id=id)
        q = get_object_or_404(AppA, pk=id)
        q.blah = request.POST.get('wibble from the form')
        ...
        return Http.....
```

in my AppB signals.py file, I have put.

```
    signal_received = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=['id'])
    def save_details(sender, uid, **kwargs):
        p = AppB.objects.get(id=id)
        p.wobble = request.POST.get('wobble from the form')
        ...
    signal.received.connect(save_details)
```

Obviously the above doesn't mention request in its arguments which seems to be necessary but if I add that, I get problems with the number of arguments.

(I have imported all the right things at the top of each file I think...hence me leaving that off.)
Any point about the above would be appreciated....e.g. does "request" need to be the first argument? It didn't seem to like me using "self" before but I have tried to copy as much as possible the example at the bottom of the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) but the extra functionality I need in the signal receiving function is flumoxing me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is `def submit` a method in a class ?

Comment: No, it was a view....so I guess that's why you don't use the "self" bit.

Comment: yeah. remove the `self` and it should work fine. I dont see a problem in the logic.

Comment: I have "solved" it by just creating some variables to get the "request.POST.get(thing)"s for AppB....and then passed them in my signal sender...Not sure if that makes sense to anybody else.

Comment: Oh ok, yeh I did actually change 'self' to 'None'...it liked me having Sender as something, maybe that's why it worked actually. Thanks